# high contrast inverse on ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: 13.04, themes, 13.10, accessibility

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and later to 13.10, I don't find anymore the theme "High contrast inverse" in the list of themes.
Still, I prefer a theme which has (i) a high contrast and (ii) has bright fonts on a dark background (e.g. white on black).
Searching the net still finds "high contrast inverse" theme references, but it is unclear to me how to install them on my ubuntu 13.x.

Jan

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
sudo apt-get install xcalib
```

Then

```
xcalib -i -a
```

[xcalib homepage here](http://xcalib.sourceforge.net/)

(Unlike vasa, some of us know what we're talking about).

Comment: xcalib -i -a works for 5 seconds then goes back.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that [the inverse option has been dropped](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/saucy/+source/gnome-themes-standard/+changelog) by upstream:

> gnome-themes-standard (3.8.1-1) unstable; urgency=low
>
> [ Josselin Mouette ]
>    * Install a cursor.theme to configure the
>   default X cursor.
>    * Set up the x-cursor-theme alternative.
>
> [ Michael Biebl ]
>    * Upload to unstable.
>    * New upstream release. 
>    * Bump Standards-Version to 3.9.4. No further changes.
>    * **The LowContrast and HighContrastInverse themes were dropped upstream**.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to create a theme myself?  If I would know (i) how to add a theme, (ii) where to find HighContrast and (iii) what is the syntax of the relevant file(s), maybe I can copy the HighContrast into HighContrastInverse files and invert all colors mentioned?

Comment: I have answered your question as originally asked. As for your subsequent questions posed in the comments, you may ask a separate question.